# Update multiple config files using PowerShell scripting

Tags: powershell

The task is to update the app Settings in web.config and app.config using the power-shell scripting. After some search I found some script to update single file but not for multiple files. Can anyone help?

```
$Config = C:\inetpub\wwwroot\TestService\Web.config
$doc = (Get-Content $Config) -as [Xml]
$obj = $doc.configuration.appSettings.add | where {$_.Key -eq 'SCVMMServerName'}
$obj.value = CPVMM02
$doc.Save($Config)
```

Comment: So you want Get-ChildItem and a for loop?

Comment: I am not sure. but that might help. Can you share how to do it?

Comment: $fileNames = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\TestService" -Recurse -Include *.config
foreach($file in $fileNames)
{  
$doc = (Get-Content $file) -as [Xml] 
If($doc -match 'key1') {
$obj1 = $doc.configuration.appSettings.add | where {$_.Key -eq 'key1'} 
$obj1.value = 'true'
$doc.Save($file) 
}
} this didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a logical set off. You can get that line which you want to update using the **-match** in *select-string* then similarly you can select the remaining things which is already there in file using **-notmatch**. 
Put them in variables. Update the line, store it back in the variable.

Then set both(the modified line variable and the remaining values which you have not modified) back to the file using **set-content**

Hope you got a set off on how to approach

Comment: $fileNames = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\TestService" -Recurse -Include *.config
foreach($file in $fileNames)
{  
$doc = (Get-Content $file) -as [Xml] 
If($doc -match 'key1') {
$obj1 = $doc.configuration.appSettings.add | where {$_.Key -eq 'key1'} 
$obj1.value = 'true'
$doc.Save($file) 
}
} this didn't work

Comment: Let me go through it

Comment: The same solution worked for me.  I used contains and my key is there 'SCVMMServerName' so it worked.  `$fileNames = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\TestService" -Recurse -Include '*.config' 
    foreach($file in $fileNames) 
        { $doc = (Get-Content $file) -as [Xml] 
        If($doc -contains 'SCVMMServerName') 
        { $obj1 = $doc.configuration.appSettings.add | where {$_.Key -contains 'key1'} $obj1.value = 'true' $doc.Save($file)} } `. Sodawillow's solution is also valid

Comment: It worked for me too. Thank you. But How can I execute this script in kudu debug console to update web.config?

Comment: @Sridhar: I have not used Kudu. I am not sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, for instance:

```
"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\TestService\Web.config",
"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\TestService\App.config" |
    ForEach-Object {
        $doc = (Get-Content $_) -as [Xml]
        $obj = $doc.configuration.appSettings.add |
            Where-Object { $_.Key -eq 'SCVMMServerName' }
        $obj.value = CPVMM02
        $doc.Save($_)
    }
```

Comment: How can I execute this script in kudu debug console to update web.config?